# Which school of thought is correct. And they belief is the truth?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, interpretation, schools

We know that vedas can be interpreted in many way. That's way there are different schools of thought in Hinduism. All of these schools understand vedas.in there own.

And they controdict each other a lot.

[image]

[image]

So the question comes which school of thought is correct. And most close to the truth and reality.

Because the world can't be dualistic, monism, and pluralistic at the same time. [*This is just an example*]. 
You can't, have bliss and no bliss ; or no consciousness or consciousness after moksha.

Comment: This definitely looks like an Opinion-based to me. In any way, asking  which is the "True-way" is not a tenet for us. What do you believe is the true way, that should form your fundamental tenet, but at the same time the next person need not have your personal tenet as their's too. Also, saying "My way is the true way and lest other ways are high way", that's is also something not a part of Hindu tenets. ***Ekam Sat Vipraa Bahuda Vadanti*, that's the the most accurate and correct way of interpreting our Hinduism and everything within it.**

Comment: @Vivikta see my question is about the controdiction arise with the Hinduism. Can which school of thought is correct. Because you either can experience bliss or you can't experience bliss. Both can not be true.

Comment: True, one can either be dead or either be alive. Light or Dark.Up or Down.etc., But, there are several ways to be dead (murder, suicide, natural, disease) and several ways to be alive ("bhakti yoga", "karma-yoga", "Gyan Yoga", etc). Our thinking is shaped by duality, but what we miss is there's a big spectrum in between those two extreme opposite polar points of the same reality, and everything transcending in that spectrum is as much true and accurate, as are those polar points in that same spectrum.

Comment: @Vivikta I have edited it. If you still find a problem please tell I will edit

Comment: I don't have any problem with it. It's just that, this question irrespective of 'n' edits will generate opinions only and not something explicitly verifiable via scriptures . Plus, it's in many ways very similar to [your previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45058/why-do-enlightened-people-contradict-each-other) - which was good. Same points in that answers are applicable in here too.

Comment: See there is one concept called God and scriptures which reveal him. In this everyone one agrees how to interpret the scripture which reveal him that us where religious school have different methods so being outside Hinduism it's very difficult nut to crack because it's all encrypted you can just read the scripture apply direct meaning  and it can reveal something and leave at that that is what an outsider would do

Comment: Relative and absolute coexist.

Comment: Maybe you can edit-ask about the various arguments each School of Thought, generally presents in debates or commentaries to defend their beliefs and thus, why their beliefs might be considered to be true, by anyone. That way it might not be Opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the fact that the Vedas are interpreted in different ways is something that is really wrong with some people. The Vedas were *never* written down, it was revealed via the breath of Prajapati Brahma about 3.11 trillion years ago (if you go by modern calculations). Vedas need to be learned as is by *shishyas* who hear it from their *Guru*. To get a sense of the purpose and the meaning behind what is heard in Vedic hymns, Puranas and Upanishads are present.

Coming to monism and contemporary schools of thought, Adi Shankaracharya's commentaries need to be focused upon. The various interpretations possible of the Puranas, Smritis, Upanishads are all beautifully summarized in those commentaries.

Comment: HI!! Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) and specifically [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Please go through them, and have an enriching journey ahead!